# How to change the update rate in TinyGPS++?

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, adafruit, frequency, tinygps

I am working with TinyGPS++ library and Arduino-nano and I want to change the update rate.
I worked before with Adafruit GPS and uses the below code for updating it.

```
// Set the update rate
 GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);   // 1 Hz update rate
```

I have also worked with `NMEAGPS.h` to update every 30sec.

```
gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK220,30000") );        //update 1time in 30s
```

So how to change the upsate rate for TinyGPS++ library? as I want to update 1 time in 30seconds.

Comment: I looked at the source code and it appears that the library checks for a new complete sentance as fast as you call the method encode.  From your question, it is not clear if this library is working too slow or too fast for your application.  But it does appear your application is in charge of any desired delay.

Comment: @st2000 I just want an update after every 30second.

Comment: If your code does not need to do anything else, I'm thinking you can simply call delay milliseconds with 30000 each time in between calling encode().  If you would like to do other things during that time, then you need to implement a state machine.

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Comment: [This example TinyGPS code](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPS/blob/master/examples/simple_test/simple_test.ino) appears to attempt to grab new GPS data once a second.  Guessing, if you increase the loop counter on line 30 from 1000 to 30000, the delay will increase from once a second to once every 30 seconds.

Comment: @st2000 I am using TinyGPS++ library and the above code is of TinyGPS which is correct answer to my question but there is a function `isUpdated` in TinyGPS++ , so that function and the code you suggested are equivalent?

Comment: Is [this the code for TinyGPS](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPS) you are talking about? I don't see "isUpdated" anywhere in the code.

Comment: Oh, bet you are talking about [his other GPS project](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus).  But I still don't see "isUpdated" in his source code.  Ah, that's because the code is so short he just puts the code in the header file.  All that's going on is that he returns (exposes) the true / false bool value of a private variable named updated.  The method does not accept a formal parameter.  And all it can return is True or False. Doesn't look like it has anything to do w/time.  It just gets set true or false depending on the last method you happen to call.

Comment: @st2000 So should i use the code you suggested or else use `isUpdated` ? [this code uses `isUpdated`](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/blob/master/examples/KitchenSink/KitchenSink.ino)

Comment: This is the example code. Not the library code. But you know that, right? It looks like "isUpdated" is used so as to only allow printing the values after the GPS module has updated the values. But that's likely way faster than what you want.  You wanted to print out data once every 30 seconds. So you have to add your own code to add a delay. A GPS module is a complex radio receiver with its own processor of which you do not have full control. On a good day it might see a dozen US (GPS), Russian (GLONASS) and other satellites. With that many satellites there will be a lot of data to print out.